# Two matrices of same height, but different number of rows

Tags: amsmath, arrays

[image]

I want to have two matrices of the same height. 
In the 1st matrix, how can I replace `X \\ \ddots` with a single row (e.g. with the content `x x x`) so that this single row is centered vertically?

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{multirow} % ?
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\left(\begin{array}{c c c c} 
A1 \\
X \\ 
\ddots  \\ 
A4
\end{array}\middle) 
\cdot
\middle(  \begin{array}{c c c c} 
B1 & & & \\ 
& B2 & & \\ 
& & \ddots & \\ 
& & &  B4
\end{array}    \right)$

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `A` column vector and the `B` square matrix do not appear to be conformable. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a solution with the environment `{NiceArray}` of the package `nicematrix`. In that environment, you merge cells with the command `\Block` both vertically and horizontally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{(c)!{\,}c!{\,}(cccc)}
A1 &\Block{*-1}{\cdot}& B1 \\
\Block{2-1}{xxx}
   &                  &    & B2 \\
   &                  &    &    & \ddots \\
A4 &                  &    &    &        & B4 
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: (+1) You might want to use `\begin{NiceArray}{(c)!\,c!\,(cccc)}` to get the same spacing that you would have with two separate matrices.

Comment: @Sandy G: You are right. I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use a phantom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
  A1 \\
  X\vphantom{\begin{matrix}B2 \\ \ddots\end{matrix}} \\
  A4
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
B1 & & & \\
& B2 & & \\
& & \ddots & \\
& & &  B4
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]